# Asymptotics of coefficients of a power series

Tags: statistics

Does anybody know what the second-order asymptotic for the coefficients of a power series means? Can you let me know where I can read more about higher order asymptotics.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general in asymptotic analysis, a second-order asymptotic approximation is an asymptotic approximation to the difference between the approximated function and its first-order asymptotic approximation. In other words, suppose that a function $f(x)$ is asymptotically approximated by $f_1(x)$: $f(x)=f_1(x)+o(f_1(x))$ (if necessary see  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) for an explanation of little-$o$ notation). Then the second-order asymptotic approximation would be an asymptotic approximation to $f(x)-f_1(x)$, that is, a function $f_2(x)$ such that $f_2(x)=o(f_1(x))$ and $f(x)=f_1(x)+f_2(x)+o(f_2(x))$.

Comment: Thanks very much. your explanation helped me a lot.